# stuck trying to append a Meme for my meme generator

Tags: javascript, append

I'm stuck trying to append a meme to the page for an assignment I have, here are the requirements for the assignment:

Meme Generator
For this assignment, you’ll be building a meme generator in the browser using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Your generator should consist of a form that accepts a link to an image, text for the top of the meme, and text for the bottom of the meme. When the user submits the form, use JavaScript to append to the DOM a div which contains the meme, including the image and its text.

Requirements

User should be able to submit a form on the page to generate a new meme on the page, and should be able to add multiple memes to the page by submitting the form multiple times.
Users should be able to click on a button to remove a meme from the page.
When the meme form is submitted, values in the form inputs should be cleared.

here's what I have so far, I'm getting an error:

memeproject.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')
at HTMLFormElement. (memeproject.js:13)

```
const form = document.querySelector("#memeform");
const topInput= document.querySelector('input[name="top"]');
const bottomInput= document.querySelector('input[name="bottom"]');
const img= document.querySelector('input[name="image"]');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    const memeform = document.createElement("div");
    const topInput= document.createElement("div");
    const bottomInput = document.createElement("div");
    const img = document.createElement("img");

    img.src= document.getElementById("imageLink").value;
    topText.classlist.add("topText");
    topInput.innerHTML= document.getElementById("topText").value;
    
    bottomInput.classList.add("bottomText");
    bottomInput.innerHTML= document.getElementByIc("bottomText").value;

    memeform.classList.add("meme");
    memeform.append(textTop);
    memeform.append(textBottom);
    memeform.append(img);
    let memeLocation = document.getElementById("location");
    memeLocation.append(meme);

form.reset()
});
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
   h1 {text-align: center;}
   h2 {text-align: center;}
   p {text-align: center;}
   div {text-align: center;}
  
   </style>


   
  
   <h1>DANK MEME MAKER THINGY</h1>
   <form id="memeform">
      <p><h2>Top Text: <input id="topText" type="text" name="top"></h2>

      <h2></he>Bottom Text: <input id="bottomText" type="text" name="bottom"></h2>

       <h2>Image Link: <input id="imageLink" type="url" name="image"></h2>



       <div style="text-align:center">  
           <input id="Create Meme!" type="submit" value="Create Meme!"> 
       </div>  

     
       <div id="location"></div> 
      </p>
     </form>
   <script src="memeproject.js"></script>
   <div> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's typo error, it should be `classList` not `classlist` with capital L.

Answer (score 0):

You did not find `topText` by `querySelector` which is not defined.

That is why you got error in line 13

Comment: got it, thank you!!! had a couple other syntax errors as well I got it kind of working now